# SQL Server: Alternate Assigning a Row based on a criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a work flow spreadsheet were I want to equally distribute the list based on the location between members of the team.

I.E. 
10 rows to assign in 2 states, broken down as follows:

7 rows in Virginia

3 rows in Utah

I want to assign the rows in each state to the members of the team in that state.

So if Jane and John are the team members for Utah and Jack and Jill were the team members for Virginia it would assign like so:

```
Row 1  || AcctNo || City || Virginia || Jill

Row 2  || AcctNo || City || Utah     || Jane 

Row 3  || AcctNo || City || Utah     || John

Row 4  || AcctNo || City || Virginia || Jack

Row 5  || AcctNo || City || Utah     || Jane

Row 6  || AcctNo || City || Virginia || Jill

Row 7  || AcctNo || City || Virginia || Jack

Row 8  || AcctNo || City || Virginia || Jill

Row 9  || AcctNo || City || Virginia || Jack

Row 10 || AcctNo || City || Virginia || Jill
```

Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks!

edit:

@BaconBits essentially this is what the data looks like now:

[image]

I want to assign the rows like
case when State = Virginia then 'Jill' or 'Jack' (alternating)
     when State = Utah then 'Jane' or 'John' (alternating)

So it looks like this:

[image]

Edit 2:

My query looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you please share you table structures and the sample data that should be used to create this result?

Comment: My initial reaction would be to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER([...]) - 1` to start with 0, modulus, `COUNT()`, and CTEs, but it's hard to say without knowing what the tables look like.

Comment: @BaconBits essentially this is what the data looks like now:

Comment: @BaconBits sorry, i adding pictures of the data sets

Comment: You were better off with the text.  Just format it as code by putting four spaces at the start of each line and it will use a fixed width font.

Comment: Ok, so, how does the database know that Jack and Jill work in Virginia, but Jane and John work in Utah?  Where are their assignments?

Comment: @BaconBits i have a temp table set up that assigns the employee to the state; #EmployeeAssigned

Comment: Show that table on your question and the data on it.

Comment: @JorgeCampos edited the post to add the query

Comment: I was working on a solution before you updated and showed your query there. I think my solution still applies though, you would need to use your select statement to insert into the account temp table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea of this is to loop through the accounts table, ordered by state (or whatever joins your people to the table). While doing this, use an index/cursor for the people table and assign them accordingly.

Using the index you can keep track of which person to assign to each appointment/account, and reset it back to the first person once you don't have any more people left.

I used temp tables (actually [table variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx)) to give people an easily run-able solution to this problem.

```
declare @tempTablePeople TABLE 
( 
    [name] varchar(50), 
    [state] varchar(50), 
    [order] int
)
INSERT INTO @tempTablePeople 
VALUES
('Jack', 'Virginia', 1),
('Jill', 'Virginia', 2),
('Ron', 'Florida', 1),
('Bob', 'Florida', 2),
('Scott', 'Florida', 3);

declare @tempTableStateAccts TABLE 
( 
    [AcctNo] int,
    [state] varchar(50)
)
INSERT INTO @tempTableStateAccts 
VALUES
(22234, 'Virginia'),
(32432, 'Virginia'),
(02342, 'Florida'),
(43423, 'Virginia'),
(69449, 'Virginia'),
(33233, 'Florida'),
(52342, 'Florida'),
(33342, 'Florida'),
(77742, 'Florida'),
(69429, 'Virginia')



declare @tempTableStateAcctsPeople TABLE 
(
    [AcctNo] int,
    [state] varchar(50),
    [name] varchar(50)
)


DECLARE @currentAcct int;
DECLARE @currentState varchar(50);
DECLARE @lastState varchar(50);
DECLARE @currentNameIndex int;
DECLARE @currentName varchar(50);
```

The meat of the query is here where you loop through the rows of the state accounts table using an index to keep track. Notice that you need to order by state in order to get the desired result (otherwise your index would be reset early).

```
SET @currentNameIndex = 1;
WHILE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM @tempTableStateAccts)
BEGIN 
    -- Get current variables for insert from current row : MUST ORDER BY STATE if you want person order to not skip anyone at the start
    SELECT @currentAcct = AcctNo, @currentState = [state] FROM @tempTableStateAccts ORDER BY [state]
    -- Reset Index if on a new state
    IF @lastState IS NULL OR @lastState != @currentState
        SET @currentNameIndex = 1
    SET @lastState = @currentState
    -- If no current name then reset index to 1
    SET @currentName = ISNULL
                        ( 
                                (SELECT name FROM @tempTablePeople WHERE [state] = @currentState AND [order] = @currentNameIndex), 
                                (SELECT name FROM @tempTablePeople WHERE [state] = @currentState AND [order] = 1)
                        )
    SET @currentNameIndex = ISNULL
                        ( 
                                (SELECT @currentNameIndex FROM @tempTablePeople WHERE [state] = @currentState AND [order] = @currentNameIndex), 
                                1
                        )

    -- Get current person for this state based on index
    SELECT @currentName = name FROM @tempTablePeople WHERE [state] = @currentState AND [order] = @currentNameIndex

    INSERT INTO @tempTableStateAcctsPeople
    VALUES
    (
        @currentAcct, 
        @currentState,
        @currentName
    )
    SET @currentNameIndex = @currentNameIndex + 1
    DELETE FROM @tempTableStateAccts WHERE AcctNo = @currentAcct
END
-- View final data
SELECT * FROM @tempTableStateAcctsPeople
```

You can paste both parts of the SQL script, in order, and run it to see the results.

```
AcctNo  state       name
32432   Virginia    Jack
69429   Virginia    Jill
22234   Virginia    Jack
69449   Virginia    Jill
43423   Virginia    Jack
77742   Florida     Ron
33342   Florida     Bob
52342   Florida     Scott
33233   Florida     Ron
2342    Florida     Bob
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stackoverflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.